# Problem for installing package for specific Python version via apt-get on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, apt-get

I have two Python versions on my Pi4: 3.11 is default and I manually added 3.9. Both are working fine. Now I have to install a package via apt-get, because there is no pip version of it: `sudo apt-get install python3-pycoral`

The problem is now that the package requires a Python version < 3.10 but apt-get is always trying to install it for Python 3.11.

I tried to set an alias in my path. So when I call `python` or `python3` from terminal, Python 3.9 opens. I also tried to find a way to change the default Python path for get-apt downloaded packages, but I found out that is is not possible.

Comment: `apt` does not install packages for specific Python versions, it always installs for the default Python version of the OS. If you try to fiddle with the  installation process expects side-effects like broken `apt` or system.

Comment: But it somehow checks my default python version, because this is the output ```The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-pycoral : Depends: python3-tflite-runtime (= 2.5.0.post1) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: python3 (< 3.10) but 3.11.2-1+b1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.```  so somehow it is checking against my default python version.

Comment: don't really have an answer to the question posted but a suggestion, googling the packaged send me to the github page with instructions on how to compile and install via pip, that could be a workaround.

Comment: You broke apt already. Try to reverse what you did.

Comment: @KlausD. from where do you know that it is broken? I am unexperienced with linux and thanks for the answers!

Comment: Did you actually read the message?

Comment: Saw [this](https://pypi.org/project/pycoral/) on PyPi, don't know if it's similar to the package you want. It appears to support python 3.6 - 3.7.

Comment: @KlausD. Yes i did, but for other packages apt-get worked fine, so i did not consider that the apt-get is broken. This is unfortunately the wrong package.

Comment: i already solved it with .whl files